# Convolving a each row of a 2D matrix with a vector

Tags: python, numpy, convolution

I have a 1000000x1000 (MxN) matrix **A**. I have another vector **b** of size L. I need to convolve each row of the 2D matrix **A** with the vector **b**. How can I do this in python?

I tried,
`C = np.convolve(A, b)`

But I get an error saying

```
in convolve return multiarray.correlate(a, v[::-1], mode)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [scipy's convolve2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html)

```
C = scipy.signal.convolve2d(A, b)
```

just make sure `len(b.shape) == 2` (meaning it is a 2 dimensional array, with one dimension of size 1)

This will work because the `b` filter will slide over each row of `A`, yielding a new row in C, then stride over to the next row, doing the same, creating another row, and so forth.